# Describe not returning Inactive picklist values via API

Tags: soap-api, picklist, metadata-api, tooling-api

I'm using Partner API to describe salesforce schema.
For some reason, in picklist fields I only see the active values (although there's a field "getActive()")

Is this a limitation or am I doing something wrong? how can I get the Inactive picklist values?

My code is along the lines of:

```
    obj = partnerConnection.describeSObject("Lead");
    for (Field f : obj.fields) {

       if (FieldType.picklist.equals(f.getType()) || FieldType.multipicklist.equals(f.getType())) {
         for (PicklistEntry e : f.getPicklistValues())  {
         if (e.getActive()) {
            // This is OK       
         }
         else
         {
            // This part is not reached, seems Inactive values are not returned ...
         }
       }
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling the isActive() method? Im not sure what getActive() is? Take a look at the [PicklistEntry class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_PicklistEntry.htm).

Comment: Vote for idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003biYQAQ to have Salesforce implement this, for the current release there is no way to obtain inactive picklist values

Answer (score 5):

I believe this to be a current limitation of the API for picklist fields.

I tried as well to get field metadata for a deactivated picklist value. It didn't come back, even though there is an `active` property.

It appears the same problem exists in the REST API with the /describe resource or a tooling API query against FieldDefinition - [Obtain the complete list of Picklist values via REST API (both active and inactive)](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000XfdFQAS)

The limitation even goes to the Apex class. E.g. the following won't return inactive picklist values:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Account.Rating.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> P = F.getPicklistValues();
System.debug(P);
```

The Metadata API used to expose a [Picklist](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_picklist.htm) Metadata type, but for v38.0 and later it switched to [ValueSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvalueset.htm).

I think most of the problems stem from `Picklist` in the older Metadata API not exposing a IsActive property. However, [CustomValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customvalue.htm#standardvalue), that is used from v38.0 onwards does have a isActive.

**Update:** I thought that the new Metadata API [StandardValueSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvalueset.htm) would have exposed the [`isActive` field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customvalue.htm#standardvalue). However, with the following Metadata API package it doesn't come back.

package.xml for the [Account.Rating picklist](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>AccountRating</members>
        <name>StandardValueSet</name>
    </types>
    <version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```

Response `\standardValueSets\AccountRating.standardValueSet`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StandardValueSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sorted>false</sorted>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Hot</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Warm</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Cold</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </standardValue>
</StandardValueSet>
```

[image: Deactived Picklist Value]

Comment: Thank you, this supports what I believe as well.

Is there some other API which does expose this?

Comment: @YossiVainshtein Not that I can find. All the API's seem to exclude inactive picklist values.